# How do I debug "Objects are not valid as a React child" react native error

Tags: react-native

Objects are not valid as a React child  (found: object with keys {style, title}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `View`.

I don't know what to make of the trace I've pasted, because it's not in my code at all. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

[Trace on simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4pEc.png)

index.ios.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Navigator
} from 'react-native';

import Product from './product.js';
import Services from './services.js';
import ProductsList from './productslist.js';
import AddProduct from './addProduct.js';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

const routes = [
  {
    title : 'Services',
    renderFunc : (navigator) => <Services navigator={navigator} />
  },
  {
    title : 'Marketplace',
    renderFunc : (navigator) => <ProductsList navigator={navigator}/>
  }
];

const stackNavigatorRoutes = {
  Services : {
    screen : Services,
  },
  ProductsList : {
    screen : ProductsList
  },
  Product : {
    screen : Product
  },
  AddProduct : {
    screen : AddProduct
  }
};

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  ...stackNavigatorRoutes,
},
{
    initialRouteName : 'Services',
    navigationOptions : {
        header : {
          style : {
            height : 60,
            backgroundColor : 'cadetblue'
          },
          title : 'ResiShare'
        }
    }
});

class Rs extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <AppNavigator />
        // <ProductsList />
        // <AddProduct />
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you should provide part of your code, which responsible of the error.

Comment: Added the entry point into my app, even though the trace doesn't reference it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main point of my question was to figure out to debug something like this where the trace doesn't show any of **my code**.

The answer was to just replace entry point in index.ios.js with something that works and then slowly add back components.

In this particular case, the reason for this fubar-ing was a breaking change from react-navigation (https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1413) that I didn't realize I had picked up (I definitely must've done an npm install).